# WURFL competitor for java

Tags: java, wurfl

Are there any other similar packages that help identify and provide capabilities for browser given its user agent ? I would prefer a server side tool rather than simply a Javascript alternative.

Comment: DYM this [WURFL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wurfl/info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at OpenDDR and let us know your feedback!

http://www.openddr.org

The code repository is here:
https://github.com/OpenDDRdotORG/OpenDDR-Java

Cheers!
OpenDDR Dev Team

Comment: OpenDDR can now be found on http://openddr.mobi. The code repository is here: https://github.com/OpenDDRmobi/openddr-java